# Glide errors showing two imageView when I reopen the fragment with the drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-glide

I've made this code that seems to work perfectly (I have one CircleImageView and one ImageView):

```
  user.getParseFile("photo").getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
            Glide.with(getActivity()).load(data).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).preload();


            Glide.with(getActivity()).load(data).centerCrop().into(profile);
            profile.setBorderColor(white);
            Glide.with(getActivity()).load(data).transform(new BlurTransformation(getActivity())).into(blurred);

        }
    });
```

the problem is when, with the drawer, I reopen the fragment: sometimes it loads only the first image, sometimes only the second, sometimes every two picture.
Why this? I've tried to preload images, but it doesn't works also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem: it was a

```
 toTransform.recycle();
```

method in `BlurTransformation`that causes this problem, because the Bitmap was already recycled.